# How to use an expresssion in a function avoiding a R CMD NOTE?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

In a function where I'm using {dplyr}, I'd like to use my function's argument in a condition inside a case_when() function.
Here's an example :

As explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), I want to avoid an R CMD CHECK NOTE because this function is part of a package so I like to use the `.data`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

myfonction <- function(variables) {
  
  
  res <- iris %>% 
    
    mutate(
      newvar = case_when(
        .data$paste0(variables,".Length") > 2 ~ "ok",
        TRUE ~ "no"
      )
    )
  
  res
}

result <- myfonction(variables="Petal")
result2 <- myfonction(variables="Sepal")
```

I have this error :

```
x Column `paste0` not found in `.data`.
Caused by error in `.data$paste0`:
```

Comment: Use `.data[[paste0(variables,".Length")]]`. You can only use `$` with literal values, not expressions or variables. The correct alternative is `[[ ]]`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick ! I can accept your answer if you want !